# Android WebView Not loaded New Data

Tags: android, webview

I have this WebView and I get the HTML from server.

```
 String Body = "<html> <head> <style> body { background-color: clear !important; } p,div,span,li { color:black; font-size:17px !important;background-color: clear !important;} embed, iframe, object, video {height: 160px; width: 355.0px;} img { height: 160px; width: 355.0px; } </style> </head> <body><p>" +
                    BodyDetails +
                    "</p>" +
                    "</div></p></body> </html>";

            Log.d("currentContent != null", Body);
            CustomTextViewDetail.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            CustomTextViewDetail.loadData("", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
            CustomTextViewDetail.loadData(Body, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
            CustomTextViewDetail.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            CustomTextViewDetail.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

My issue is that when I change the HTML content, web view still shows the last content not load the new content!

How to refresh or solve this issue?

Comment: Why have you called `loadData` twice?

Comment: i remove it !   but nothing change

Comment: Are you sure server has sent you a _different_ response?

Comment: yes i print it and its different !

Comment: Does ***BodyDetails***  come from server ? It is new html ? or initial?

Comment: yes  ,, i got list of html ,, and i swipe between it

Answer (score 0):

Call `myWebView.reload()` after you change the data.

Comment: Why do you call loadData twice? You don't need the first one, other then that, I think Body is a lang word in java, try changing your var name to html_body instead of Body

Comment: same issue nothing change

Comment: @FlyingNades _"I think Body is a lang word in java..."_ lol no that's not a lang word dude :)

Comment: @MeladDavid Can you post your whole code + xml? your code works just fine for me.

Comment: i post all my code in another question and mention u there